# Show Task Scheduler jobs that contain 'Actions'

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I want to see all of the Task Scheduler jobs where the 'Actions' are not blank.

I got the initial code from this link: 
[Task Scheduler in powershell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/604673/how-to-print-out-information-about-task-scheduler-in-powershell-script)

For example, I don't want to see the scheduled tasks that have the name "Optimize Start Menu Cache Files" because the 'Actions' are blank.

```cs
$sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.Connect()
$out = @()
$sched.GetFolder("\").GetTasks(0) | % {
    $xml = [xml]$_.xml

    $out += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Name" = $_.Name
        "Status" = switch ($_.State) {0 {"Unknown"} 1 {"Disabled"} 2 {"Queued"} 3 {"Ready"} 4 {"Running"}}
        "Actions" = ($xml.Task.Actions.Exec | % { "$($_.Command) $($_.Arguments)" }) -join "`n"
        "NextRunTime" = $_.NextRunTime
        "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
        "LastRunResult" = $_.LastTaskResult
        "Author" = $xml.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId
        "Created" = $xml.Task.RegistrationInfo.Date
    }
}

$out | fl Name,Status,Actions,NextRuNTime,LastRunTime,LastRunResult,Author,Created | Where-Object {($_.Actions -ne "" -and $_.Actions -eq "*powershell*" -or $_.Actions -ne $null)}
```

Comment: `... | Where-Object { $_.Actions.Execute -ne $null }`?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't get any results back.

Comment: I overlooked that you're using the COM interface. Try `... | Where-Object { $_.Actions.Exec -ne $null }`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Same thing.  No results.

Comment: Sorry, I really should stop commenting while being distracted by other things. Your problem is caused by the `Format-List` (`fl`). The cmdlet is purely for output formatting and shouldn't be used for anything else. `$out | Where-Object {$_.Actions}` should do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with the following however I cannot have multiple clauses in the where statement.

```
$sched = New-Object -Com "Schedule.Service"
$sched.Connect()
$out = @()
$sched.GetFolder("\").GetTasks(0) | % {
    $xml = [xml]$_.xml

    $out += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Name" = $_.Name
        "Status" = switch ($_.State) {0 {"Unknown"} 1 {"Disabled"} 2 {"Queued"} 3 {"Ready"} 4 {"Running"}}
        "Actions" = ($xml.Task.Actions.Exec | % { "$($_.Command) $($_.Arguments)" }) -join "`n"
        "NextRunTime" = $_.NextRunTime
        "LastRunTime" = $_.LastRunTime
        "LastRunResult" = $_.LastTaskResult
        "Author" = $xml.Task.Principals.Principal.UserId
        "Created" = $xml.Task.RegistrationInfo.Date
    }
}

$out |Where Actions -like "*powershell*"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for anything newer than windows 7.

```
get-scheduledtask |Where-Object {$_.actions -NE $Null -OR $_.actions -NE "" }
```

Comment: That didn't work.  "Optimize Start Menu Cache" tasks still appear.